# How to I calculate the AC amperage draw of a 12 volt 3 amp AC/DC transformer under full 3 amp load?

Tags: transformer

I want to calculate the 120 volt amperage draw of my 12 volt AC/DC wall adapters, most specifically, one that has a 3 amp rating that is pulling close to 3 amps.

Is there a formula for calculating the AC amps?

Example: A 36 watt 120 volt load vs. a 36 watt 12 volt load on a 120 volt AC/DC converter. I want to compare AC amps of each.

I apologize in advance if my question is not clear, but that's the best I can do.

Comment: You don't, you measure it.

Comment: I don't want to measure it, I want to calculate it. I may have twenty LEDs I want to install and I don't want to install them, measure them, then find out I am not satisfied with the result. I want to know in advance. I know there are variables, PF, etc. I just want to know an approximate draw because I might want to put 20 wall warts driving 20 36 watt LED lamps. If so, what is the amperage load so I could size the correct breaker for the 120 volt AC circuit?

Comment: Then we need the full schematics with all datasheets of all parts, since we must calculate the efficiency

Comment: You got to be kidding me!

Comment: Do you know how to calculate the efficiency in another way without knowing anything about the device?

Answer (score 2):

What PlasmaHH said is the truth. You can only figure that the power was loss-less
through the transformer. In other words since the power is (approximately) 3A X 12 VDC = 36 Watts I would estimate that the power on the primary would be the same
which is to say:

W = E X I (without the power factor) rearranged 
36W = 120 X I <=> 36W/120 = .3 Amps which again is 36W without knowing the power factor, eddy losses etc. You would need to measure the power and phase angle on the primary to know the exact measurements.

Answer (score 0):

Transformers work only on AC or alternating voltages or currents. Applying a DC voltage to a transformer will eventually damage it. That said, a transformer just "transforms" the voltage x current going in, to some other voltage x current going out. So you can shorten this to an approximation of voltage (v) and current (I) in the (primary, or input) = (secondary, or output) as: \$V_P\cdot I_P = V_S\cdot I_S\$ Note this is not entirely true, some power is always lost in the transformer, so real numbers will always be slightly different than calculations.

So if we plug in the values from your question, simplify and solve for primary current,

\$120v\cdot I_P = 12v\cdot 3A\$

\$120v\cdot I_P = 36\$

\$\require{cancel}\dfrac{\cancel{120v}\cdot I_P}{\cancel{120v}} = \dfrac{36}{120v}\$

\$I_P = 0.3A\$

Now if you were to measure the AC current on the primary side (careful, 120vAC is hazardous) you may get a reading like 0.321A. It is a little higher because some power is wasted by the transformer.

Answer (score 0):

What a good question.The answer is not 36/120 .In fact it is about twice that because Efficiency and Power factor be taken into account .For example the power factor of a cap input filter is around 64% with normal component values .If your efficiency is estimated to be say 86% then your AC current will be twice what it would be with unity power factor and no losses .